# Moving a DOM element between Bootstrap Tabs with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a project that manages different times of media. The main page is organized into 3 tabs, Images, Videos, and Slideshows. The Image and Video tabs have each have a table that uses ng-repeat to create rows based on database information. The slideshow tab has an option to create a slideshow by selecting images or videos.

Since constructing the same large table multiple times is expensive, I wanted to move the contents of the image and video tabs into the slideshow tab when it's active. I also thought it would be nice if users could pick up from where they left off, so that's another reason why moving it is appealing. I'm fairly new to Angular, and I can't seem to figure out how to do this the Angular way. If I were just using jQuery, I could select the content wrapper, detach it, and append it to the slideshow tab, but that isn't an option in this case.

Right now, I have everything stored in one large HTML file. My first thought was to break the tab contents into partials and use ng-include in multiple places, but I don't think that would allow me to use the same elements. I've also tried using jqLite to append the elements, but I'm not sure how to select the html of the selected object, rather than the angular object itself.

What's the best way for me to go about reusing these existing DOM elements?

**Edit:** This is an internal project, so I can't link to a page right now or include all of the code, but I can write out the general structure.

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Images" id="image-tab">
        <div id="image-tab-content">
            <table>
               <thead> [HEADERS ARE HERE] </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="item in itemList"> [ROW INFO] </tr> 
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Slideshows">
         <div id="slideshow-content-wrapper">
            <p>Add pictures using tables below</p>
            <tabset>
                <tab heading="Second Image Tab">
                    [MOVE image-tab-content HERE]
                </tab>
            </tabset>
         </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Hopefully that clarifies a little bit. I'm just trying to move the content of the image tab to the second image tab when you click on the slideshow tab.

Comment: Can you include some of your code or a link to the page?

Comment: I can't add full fledged code right now, but I've added a skeleton that should clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this had been solved, but I am also facing similar situation. I needed to move DOM element outside of the angular tab into the content.

I didn't want to modify the DOM manually, but I couldn't find other way around it, so this is what I did (which should work for you as well.

```
$scope.tabs = [];
$scope.addTab = function(el) {
    var tab = { title: el.data("title")};
    $scope.tabs.push(tab);
    $scope.$apply();

    var index = $scope.tabs.length - 1;
    angular.element($element.find(".tab-pane").get(index)).find("span").append(el);
};
```

So as you can see, after adding a tab, I manually retrieve the new tab, and just move the element inside. In your case, you just need to do something similar.

I know this is against the AngularJS to manipulate the DOM, but until they have a way to accept element as `content` or have an example of it, this is how I got it working.

Hope this help.